# Writing An angularToHTML Function

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I recently wrote this function which converts HTML with Vue.js directives to regular HTML:

```
function vueToHTML(vueHTML, data, onRender) {
  function onUpdated() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      onRender(this.$el.innerHTML);
    });
  }

  return new Vue({
    template: '<div>' + vueHTML + '</div>',
    el: document.createElement('div'),
    data: Object(data),
    mounted: onUpdated,
    updated: onUpdated
  });
}
```

I can thusly call this function by doing something like this:

```
vueToHTML(
  '<div v-for="a in [1,2,3]">{{a}}</div>',
  null,
  function(output) {
    console.log('Output:', output);
  }
);
```

And the following will be output:

> `Output: <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>`

I can also specify the data (AKA scope) variables:

```
vueToHTML(
  '<div v-for="a in arr">{{a}}</div>',
  { arr: [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] },
  function (output) {
    console.log('Output:', output);
  }
);
```

This will result in the following:

> `Output: <div>9</div><div>8</div><div>7</div><div>6</div><div>5</div><div>4</div><div>3</div><div>2</div><div>1</div>`

What I want to do is create a similar function which will work with Angular.  How can I write a function with the following signature that will work with Angular and will call the callback function with the processed HTML?

```
function angularToHTML(html, data, callback) {
  // Code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Angular components are precompiled, to be able to do that on the fly you are probably going to have to have some of the build pipeline or debug mode in your app.

Comment: Ok, I will stick with Vue.js for the short term but I will come back to what you said in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: @AdrianBrand I originally was using this function in a Grafana panel plugin that I made but then I decided to use Vue.js in a different way.  This is the plugin that I made that I wanted to be able to simply leverage angular with to provide similar functionality:  https://github.com/westc/grafana-vuehtml-panel